A Special Class of Complete Multipartite Graphs
A k-partite graph is a graph whose vertices are (or can be) partitioned into k different independent sets. If $k \geq 3$, we call it a complete multipartite graphs. Some special classes of complete multipartite graphs play vital roles in various kinds of fields. For example, Turán graphs are important instances in extremal graph theory.
I'm now working on complete multipartite graphs that satisfy a certain property. We use $n_1, n_2, ..., n_r$ to denote the sizes of partites in a complete $r$-partite graph. Is there any formal name for this special class of complete multipartite graphs if $n_i=k*n_{i+1}$ where $k$ is a positive integer and $i \in \{1, ..., r-1\}$?

It feels unlikely to me that there is a name for this special type of graph. It is very specific. I could be wrong though
